# how to set an Image size that works on screens of all resolution?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How I can make an image like [this](http://themeforest.net/item/the-meetup-conference-event-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/12477772)? 
My image doesn't work on bigger desktop screens.
This is my code for image size:

```
style="width:100%;height:100%;"
```

Comment: They've probably set a background image to the body tag (or whatever the container tag is). Once you've done that you can set `background-size:cover;` to cover the entire div whilst keeping the aspect ratio. (Note: This will probably clip parts of the image to fit)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you can give `<img />` the following CSS:

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

**Snippet**

```css
img {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" />
```